# "COPY failed: no source files were specified" when Dockerfile is not in root directory on Docker Hub

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, dockerhub

When I run my application through `docker-compose up`, it builds and runs without any issues. When I try to host it on Docker Hub, it fails to build with the error `COPY failed: no source files were specified`. I believe it is because the Dockerfile is not in the root directory.

My folder structure is like this:

```
root
-- docker-compose.yml
-- app
   -- Dockerfile
   -- package.json
   -- package-lock.json
   -- src
      -- .....
```

My Dockerfile is below, and when I run `docker-compose up` (which points to the Dockerfile within `/app`) it runs fine:

```
FROM node:8.10.0-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install --production
COPY . /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 4000
CMD ["npm", "run", "app"]
```

I am wanting to host my project on Docker Hub, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Step 1/7 : FROM node:8.10.0-alpine
---> adc4b0f5bc53
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
Removing intermediate container 743246352cea
---> 3dcb720d4618
Step 3/7 : COPY package*.json /usr/src/app/
COPY failed: no source files were specified
```

The build rules I've set to point to the correct Dockerfile location is below:

[image: Docker Hub build rules showing Dockerfile location as app/Dockerfile]

Is my Dockerfile wrong, or am I not configuring Docker Hub correctly when I try to hook it up to my GitHub repo?

For context, the GitHub repo is [here](https://github.com/james-work-account/github-user-search/tree/5a24882b92af08f47bf127151b75e39399a91872).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the build configuration, you need to configure the "build context" directory rather than changing the Dockerfile location. Otherwise, the build will run in the parent of your github repo where the `package*.json` files do not exist. Note the column after "Dockerfile location" when configuring automated builds in the example below:

[image]

Comment: I don't see a "Build Context" column when trying to create a new repository. How did you get that?

Comment: @JamesWhiteley click the "Configure automated builds" button at the top assuming you are using Docker Hub to run your builds.

Comment: I didn't know that I had to add that field _after_ initializing the Hub repository. This worked, thanks!

Comment: @BMitch It's clear to me that you need to set a build context - the Q is where are my files stored - in what dir ?? So I would know what context I should use.

Comment: @Mkey I don't follow your question. This should probably be a new question rather than a comment so you can provide more details.

Comment: @Dr.House my sourcecode was in the `app` directory (see the original question) so my build context is `/app`. Sorry I didn't see this reply until today - better late than never!